# It doesn't count character in correctly if give one name but counts correctly if given 2 names

Tags: count

#first code
a = "atharv"

for i in a :

```
print(len(i))
```

B = "atharv","raj"
for e in B :
print(len(e))

Then it prints 6 and 3

So in first code
so this should give me number of alphabet in my name but it give 1 six time

But in second code
If I add another name it works correctly it gives output

Answer (score 0):

```
a = "atharv"
```

This creates a [string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#textseq). Elements of a string are individual characters, of which there are 6 here. If you iterate over `a`, you will get `"a"`, `"t"`, `"h"`, `"a"`, `"r"` and `"v"`. Each character in Python is represented as a one-character string, its length `1`.

```
b = "atharv", "raj"
```

This creates a [tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuples). A tuple items here are `"atharv"` and `"raj"`, so the length is 2, and iterating over it will give you `"atharv"` and `"raj"`.

Since the types of `a` and `b` are completely different, it is not a surprise that they behave differently.

If you want to create a tuple of length 1, you must include a comma:

```
a = "atharv",
```

However, most people here would use a [list](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#lists), not a tuple:

```
a = ["atharv"]
b = ["atharv", "raj"]
```